# Selection based on truth table

Tags: filtering

This is probably an easy one…

I have a list and truth table for example

```
list = {a1, b1, c1, d1}; 
truthTable = {True, False, False, True};
```

Based on the truthTable I’d like to select elements in the list. For instance, in the example above should return {a1,d1}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {a1, b1, c1, d1}
truthTable = {True, False, False, True}

Pick[list,truthTable]
```

> {a1, d1}

Comment: Thank you… I knew there was an function for it! After a long lapse of MMA, I’m a little rusty